# Как изменить название программы на панели задач?

Tags: delphi-7

Привет всем!

У меня есть программа - аналог диспетчера задач, написанная на Delphi. Данный программный продукт при запуске на панели  задач имеет название, не соответствующее названию программе, как можно поменять?

Помогите, пожалуйста, только начинаю изучать Delphi и срочно надо разобраться в этой проге.

Answer (score 1):

Это настраивается в свойствах приложения вот здесь:

```
Project -> Options -> (вкладка)Application -> Title
```

Answer (score 1):

Это делается проще:

`Application.Title := 'Имя программы';`